# Expressing this SQL as Mongo Query

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb

I want to figure out the most active users on my site.

I have records of the form

```
{
    "_id" : "db1855b0-f2f4-44eb-9dbb-81e27780c796",
    "createdAt" : 1360497266621,
    "profile" : { "name" : "test" },
    "services" : { "resume":
        { "loginTokens" : [{
                "token" : "82c01cb8-796a-4765-9366-d07c98c64f4d",
                "when" : 1360497266624
            },
            {
                "token" : "0e4bc0a4-e139-4804-8527-c416fb20f6b1",
                "when" : 1360497474037
            } ]
        },
        "twitter" : {
            "accessToken" : "9314Sj9kKvSyosxTWPY5r57851C2ScZBCe",
            "accessTokenSecret" : "UiDcJfOfjH7g9UiBEOBs",
            "id" : 2933049,
            "screenName" : "testname"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to select users and order by the number of `loginTokens`.
In `MySQL` it would be something like:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(logins) AS logins 
FROM users 
GROUP BY id ORDER BY logins DESC
```

I've tried this on querymongo.com and i got an error (can't work with aliases/ cant order by non-column names)

What's the Mongo way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just converted:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(logins)
FROM users 
GROUP BY id
```

To:

```
db.users.group({
    "key": {
        "id": true
    },
    "initial": {
        "countlogins": 0
    },
    "reduce": function(obj, prev) {
        prev.countlogins++;
    }
});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you said using the aggregation framework:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {$unwind: '$services.resume.loginTokens'},
    {$group: {_id: '$_id', logins: {$sum: 1}}},
    {$sort: {logins: -1}}
])
```

This should do the trick.